# Grouping values with regular expressions regex

Tags: regex, excel, csv

I have got a list of names within an Excel sheet (also in csv) and I made groups with the origin of the names.

This is what the groups I made look like.

[image: This is what the groups I made look like]

Now I want to add a new column with the group name behind the name.

This is what I want to obtain.

[image: This is what the groups I made look like]

How do I get this? Do I have to use regualar expressions for this?

Comment: You put a python tag but it has been removed during an edition. If you want to get more answers in python, I suggest you specify it in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regex here. For instance, you can use the csv module of python.

**old.csv**

```
groups,,,
Dutch,Lore,Kilian,Daan
German,Marte,,
USA,Eva,Judith,
```

**python script using `import csv`**

```
import csv

rows = []

with open('old.csv','r') as old_csv:
  old = csv.reader(old_csv, delimiter=',')
  old.next()
  for row in old:
    for name in row[1:]:
      if name:
        rows.append({'name':name,'group':row[0]})

with open('new.csv','w') as new_cvs:
  fieldnames = ['name', 'group']
  new = csv.DictWriter(new_cvs, fieldnames=fieldnames)
  new.writer.writerow(new.fieldnames)
  new.writerows(rows)
```

**new.csv**

```
name,group
Lore,Dutch
Kilian,Dutch
Daan,Dutch
Marte,German
Eva,USA
Judith,USA
```

You can also use xlrd and xlwt modules but you have to install them because they aren't standard.